# How do I get Windows XP to change where My Videos, My Music and My Pictures folders are pointing to, to make them act like Linux symlinks?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I love how in Linux you can link to folders.

Is there some way to get the same functionality in Windows XP, maybe by editing the Registry.

Comment: I realised once I asked this question that Shortcuts are just files with the .lnk extension, Windows interprets these. - I have edited the question to clarify my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP doesn't do symbolic links; Vista is the first Microsoft OS that does. XP has NTFS junction points but they are not as useful as they only work with local directories.

On Vista if you are symbolic linking to a remote system, that system must also support symlinks.

---

If you look in these two places in the registry you can change where each "special folder" is located / points to.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer but you can change the location of the entire My Documents folder in XP. I always used to do this with XP to move all user docs to a 2nd HDD.

1. Right click on the My Documents icon (either on Desktop or Start Menu)
2. Select Properties
3. Select Target tab
4. Click Move
5. Select your new location
6. Apply or OK
7. Click Yes to Move Documents

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would [NTFS Junction Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) help? There's a little utility called [NTFS Link](http://elsdoerfer.name/=ntfslink) that helps make them easier to manipulate.